# How to load mongojs module

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, requirejs, mongojs

I've some problem using mongojs. When I try to call a function (that is defined in a javascript file) from an html page I've got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "mongojs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

In the file js I connect to mongojs through these lines:

```
var databaseUrl = "webIndexDb";
var collections = ["clusters"];
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);
```

In file html I have import require.js

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.5/r.js'></script>
```

what goes wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to include the script first. Try moving it up right before the closing head tag.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, could you please explain better?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I meant try putting it just before the `</head>` tag. Sorry the editor removed my code in the answer.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. If you get something else in mind please do not hesitate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

requirejs docs suggest doing this, which did work for me in exactly the same situation:

```
$(function(require) {
    var databaseUrl = "192.168.50.103/data";
    var collections = ["spot_daily"];
    var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);
});
```